# Symfony 2.0/Doctrine2 autoincrement unique text field

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my Symfony 2.0 application, I must import and create users from csv file.

I have no problem to do that, but I also need to generate an unique email for each user (because I have a webmail in my application,  so I need to create an internal mail adress )

I would like to know if there is any best practice to auto-increment a duplicate value of unique text field (`john.doe@mydomain.com`, `john.doe_1@mydomain.com` ...)

My first idea would be to do the verification in a prepersist event, but maybe there is better solution.

Comment: The best solution is to write a function yourself (prepersist is a good choice). Define your rules and apply them. Have fun :)

Comment: thank you for the answer, I'll do it like this for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply autoincrementing may have concurrency issues if the transaction has a pause or delay.

Adding a nano-second timestamp will effectively guarantee unique, but the email addresses will be unwieldly without an aliaser or autocomplete.

Alternatively, you can start a social campaign to eliminate duplicate names from the entire human population.  That might take a few [thousand] months.

Comment: you are right, I am aware of this and am looking for a solution.

Unfortunately, I do not have time to start a social campaign but it's an idea.